# How can I get the mean image of several images in OpenCV(using C++)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am computing the mean image of two images and don't know the correct method to use the function mean() in OpenCV.

```
Mat img1,img2,img3;
img1=imread("picture1.jpg");
img2=imread("picture2.jpg");    
img3=mean(img1,img2);
```

However it says

```
R6010
-abort() has been recalled
```

How can I get the average of img1 & img2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to opencv documentation :

*"The function mean calculates the mean value M of array elements, independently for each channel, and return it:"*

This mean it should return you a scalar for each layer of you image, and the second parameter is a mask of pixels to where to perform computation

have you simply tried to do something like this ?

img3 = (img1+img2) * 0.5;

[EDIT] to avoid some losses if values are > 255, you probably should convert your images to CV_32F, before performing computations, then cast the result of you operation into CV_8U using the cv::convertTo [opencv documentation on ConvertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto)

Comment: 5 years too late but maybe usefull for people like me that find this answer later: I think if you first multiply by 0.5 and then add them up you avoid the losses that result from values larger than 255.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `cv::accumulate` :

```
Mat img3 = Mat::zeros(img1.size(), CV_32F); //larger depth to avoid saturation
cv::accumulate(img1, img3);
cv::accumulate(img2, img3);
img3 = img3/2;
```